# AWS S3 object - WRITE ACL Permission returned although it is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, object, amazon-s3, acl

According to AWS documentation ACL WRITE permission on S3 object is ["Not applicable"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html).
This option is also not available in the consul when editing the access control list of the object.
So how come when I'm getting the object ACL using the API (.net sdk, AmazonS3Client.GetACLAsync()), one of the ACLs is WRITE?

Comment: Could you show us what API you used to get the object ACL?

Comment: .net sdk, AmazonS3Client.GetACLAsync(GetACLRequest aclRequest).  aclRequest.Key = objectPath